# Simple question regarding integrals over the surface of a sphere

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I started studying to PDE's and at the moment I'm reading the Laplace equation and specifically the mean value property. In this proof it is used that

$
\int_{\partial B(x,s)} u(y) dS(y) = u(x)n\alpha (n) s^{n-1}
$

Why is this true? I can't really seem to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is a proof about the mean value property of harmonic functions, i.e. solutions of an elliptical PDE. What is $B$, $u$, $\alpha$, $s$? I can guess some, but I do not have your proof to look them up.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the **mean** value property, which requires the integral to be divided by the size of the region. If $u$ is harmonic in $U$ then for any $B(x,r)$ contained in $U$ we have that 
$$\frac{1}{|B(R)|}\int_{B(x,R)}u(y)\,dy=\frac{1}{|\partial B(R)|}\int_{\partial B(x,R)}u(y)\,dy=u(x).$$
The formula you have comes from multiplying out $|\partial B(R)|$ in the latter equality.

I.e., $|\partial B(R)|=n\alpha(n)R^{n-1}$, where $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the $n$ dimensional unit ball.